# Get Max Date - For Every Transaction

Tags: date, get, max

in my table one of column is Status and Date
if suppose i want to get max(date) for each state then i can use group by of date

But here my problem is i want to get max(date) for each transaction 
NOT FOR EACH STATUS

that means, my status values like ,**create / modify / modify / submit / reject / modify / submit / reject / modify / submit**
now i want to get each transaction along with max date like

**- create /*(only one)* modify / submit / reject / *(again)* modify /submit
   / reject / modify / Submit...**

Can any one please suggest me to find solution for the above.

Thanks in advance

Joe

Comment: Can you give an example of your data and the output you want to achieve in order to make the question a little clearer?

Comment: Max date for each status or the most recent date of as status change?

Comment: Let me give clear example
my table struct like
Status -    Date
Created - 01-08-2011
Modify -  02-08-2011
Modify -  03-08-2011
Modify -  04-08-2011
Submit -  04-08-2011
Reject -  05-08-2011
Modify -  05-08-2011
Modify -  06-08-2011
Submit -  07-08-2011
Reject -  07-08-2011
Modify -  07-08-2011
Modify -  08-08-2011
My Output should be
Status -    Date
Created - 01-08-2011
Modify -  04-08-2011
Submit -  04-08-2011
Reject -  05-08-2011
Modify -  06-08-2011
Submit -  07-08-2011
Reject -  07-08-2011
Modify -  08-08-2011

Comment: What database are you using Joe ?

Answer (score 0):

I would select all the rows sorted by create date:

```
SELECT status, created
FROM t      
WHERE  tid = 1 
ORDER BY created
```

Then filter (in the language of your choice) dropping any row that has a row after it of the same status.

However this will not quite work for you.
Your data only contains a date column and as there are many status on a given date so there will be no order for a several statuses on a single day, you can solve this by storing the date/time created.

Depending on your database it may also be possible to produce the data using an analytic query.